# How to apply js .join() method to my array after every two values in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of lat longs:

```
latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16]
```

I want to convert this into a string in this format:

```
latlon_string = "lat,lon lat,lon lat,lon"

working example:
latlon_string = "51.49,-0.05 51.48,0.16"
```

I tried using the join() method to apply a space after every two values but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Or is there a better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your array and then replace every second comma with space like this:

```
latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16];
latlon_string = latlong.join(',').replace(/(,[^,]*),/g ,'$1 ');
console.log(latlon_string); // 51.49,-0.05 51.48,0.16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.reduce()` to generate string like this.

```
var latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16]     
latlong.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
    if (currentIndex % 2 === 0) {
        return previousValue + " " + currentValue;
    }
    return previousValue + "," + currentValue;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do it with a straight call to `join`, but you could just iterate and insert commas and spaces on every other iteration

```
latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16];

var latlon_string = "";

for (var i=0; i<latlong.length; i++) {
    latlon_string += latlong[i] + ( i%2 ? ' ' : ',' );
}
```

Comment: @gurvinder372 just swap the comma and the space in the conditional :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 var latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16];
 var latlong_string = latlong.slice(0, 2).toString() + ' ' + latlong.slice(2, 4).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16];
var newArray = [];
for ( var counter = 0; counter < latlong.length; counter = counter+2 )
{
   newArray.push( latlong[ counter ] + "," + latlong[ counter + 1 ] );
}
var output = newArray.join( " " );
console.log( output  );
```

Comment: I do n;t think that is what OP wanted

Comment: @epascarello my bad, missed the join in last statement :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
  var latlong = [51.49, -0.05, 51.48, 0.16];
  var latlong_string = "";
  for (i=0;i<latlong.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
      latlong_string = latlong[i];
    }else if (i%2==1||i==1){
      latlong_string = latlong_string + "," + latlong[i];
    }else if (i%2==0){
      latlong_string = latlong_string + " " + latlong[i];
    };  
  };
```